# Is this one of the downsides of unobtrusive javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

Adding inline javascripts to the html tags (e.g. onclick, onsubmit...etc) is considered bad practice.

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return validate();">
...
</form>
<a id="link1" href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="return popup();">Link1</a>
```

But if we do it like below, is this possible that the `validate` or `popup` function does not get called because the user interacts with the page before the dom ready function is called?

```
<form id="form1">
...
</form>
<a id="link1" href="http://www.google.com/">Link1</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#form1').submit(
            //validate
            function(){...}
        );
        $('#link1').click(
            //popup
            function(){...}
        );
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: well in your code above, you do not need ready since it appears after the element. And with jQuery 1.7+, you can use on at the document level and catch stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create them disabled and then use the `ready` event to make them enabled only after the events have been bound.

Note that the `onxxx` in the HTML may try to access things that do not exist yet if you try to traverse the DOM in them, which likely causes errors and is worse than having the user wait for a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 1):

If your method is in an external file, then the form can be accessed before the script is loaded regardless of how you attach the method. It's a small tradeoff for easier maintainability and separation of concerns.

Comment: Whether the method is in an external file doesn't really matter. The script is always parsed before the browser continues to parse the rest of the page.

Comment: @Guffa are you saying it's not possible for the user to interact with the form before the script executes? Are you assuming scripts loaded in the `<head>`?

Comment: I assume that the function exists before the code that calls it, otherwise the entire qustion is moot.

Comment: @Guffa I think that is precisely the question; if you have the function defined in an external file loaded after the form, it's possible for the DOM to render before the function is defined. Less so on a fast machine/fast connection/properly architected page, but still plausible. That's the heart of my answer anyway.

Comment: In that case the answer doesn't answer the question, it answers something else. The question was about the difference between binding events inline and binding them in the `ready` event. If you load an external script at the end of the page, there is no practical difference in behaviour.